# Hibernate : is batching disabled for single table inheritance?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, batching

### Problem

I found out that hibernate's **batching does not work** for the following two classes while calling *StatelessSession#insert()*. (i.e. Prepared statements have been created for each call).

**Parent Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "950_ATC_LOG")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", length = 1)
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
public class AtcLog {

@Id
@Column(name = "ATC_LOG_ID")
private long id;

// other memebers here...
}
```

**Child Entity**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
public class AllocationLog extends AtcLog {

// some members here
}
```

But after I changed the entities to the following, hibernate started to **use batching** as expected :

**Parent Entity - NEW**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractLog {

@Id
@Column(name = "ATC_LOG_ID")
private long id;

// some members here
}
```

**Child Entity - NEW**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "950_ATC_LOG")
public class AtcLog extends AbstractLog {

@Column(name = "TYPE", length = 1, nullable = false)
private char type;

// some members here
}
```

### Question

Is hibernate batching disabled for single table inheritance? 
The [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch15.html) only says that it shall be disabled with *"identity identifier generator"* but I set the ids explicitly. 
I did not find any other reference to such problem.