# Order inserts not working with Hibernate JOINED inheritence strategy

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When using JOINED inheritence strategy hibernate is not ordering inserts and as a result batch inserts are not working.
This is causing a performance hit. Is there any way to keep using the strategy and configure hibernate to order the inserts?
I have used id generation strategy as sequence so that is not the issue.

As an example say we have abstraction `Animal`. `Dog`, `Cat` etc.. are the concrete entities.
Following are the operations.

```
Animal a = new Dog();
Animal b = new Cat();
save(a);
save(b);
```

SQL statements in console that are logged.

```
insert into animal...;
insert into dog...;
insert into animal...;
insert into cat...;
```

What I expect hibernate to do..

```
insert into animal...;
insert into animal...;
executing batch of size 2;
insert into dog..;
insert into cat..;
```

Comment: Looks like hibernate is working as expected... you save a dog first, which requires an insert to animal and an insert to dog. Then you save a cat, which in turn requires an insert to animal and an insert to cat

Comment: It is true that parent has to be inserted first. But, same is the case with any foreign key relation. I expected that as order_inserts is true, inserts should be rearranged so that batching can be performed.

Comment: You are in the same transaction of course.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500406/hibernate-is-batching-disabled-for-single-table-inheritance but it has no answer. I'd suggest looking at single table inheritance, or an alternate provider (I believe EclipseLink supports this level of statement rearranging for batching)